# Add Commission Fee to WooCommerce Checkout Based on Subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, fee

Trying to add a commission fee to the WooCommerce checkout based on 5% multiplied by subtotal. But, all I get is a blank page and the site stops working.

**This is the code:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_commission', 10, 1 ); 
function add_commission( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // global, is this needed?
    global $woocommerce;

    // get the cart subtotal
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();

    // commission fee of 5%
    $commission_fee = 0.05;
    
    // the total commission is the 5% multiplied by the subtotal
    $total_commission = $commission_fee * $subtotal;

    // apply the commission
    $cart->add_fee( 'Commission', $total_commission, true );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main error is in `get_cart_subtotal()` method, which is the formatted cart subtotal HTML (a string) that you are trying to multiply with a float number.

Instead, you should use `get_subtotal()` method *(non formatted subtotal without taxes amount)*.

So the correct code is:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_commission' ); 
function add_commission( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    // get the cart subtotal
    $subtotal = $cart->get_subtotal();

    // commission fee of 5%
    $commission_fee = 0.05;
    
    // the total commission is the 5% multiplied by the subtotal
    $total_commission = $commission_fee * $subtotal;

    // apply the commission
    $cart->add_fee( 'Commission', $total_commission, true );
}
```